# dplyr summarise evaluates custom function twice?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using `dplyr` `group_by` and `summarise` functions with custom made aggregate function, and have observed a strange behavior. It seems like the aggregate function is evaluate twice for each group.

Here is a minimal example:

```
aggFun <- function(x) { print("Inside function"); print(rnorm(1)); sum(x)}
df <- data.frame(key = rep("a", 3), val = 1:3)
df %>% group_by(key) %>% summarise(sum = aggFun(val))
```

The following is output:

```
[1] "Inside function"
[1] 0.3230769
[1] "Inside function"
[1] -0.3347653
# A tibble: 1 × 2
   key   sum
<fctr> <int>
1      a     6
```

Since there is only one group, shouldn´t the function only be evaluated once? I am experiencing the same thing in a large application, and worry that this might be bad for performance, or am I missing something?

**Solved by upgrading to GitHub version**.

Comment: Only runs once for me

Comment: I can confirm seeing the same issue with dplyr 0.5.0 and R 3.3.2

Comment: Note that this is fixed in the dplyr GitHub repro, but not in the current published version on CRAN (dplyr 0.5.0).  I added an answer to the other copy of this question (see link in the comment above) showing where it was fixed.

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading to the GitHub version solved the issue.